# About kineto-statics duality of the closed chain

Tags: kinematics

I can't understand the content from the book "Robotics Modelling, Planning and Control", page 151. Suppose that there is a manipulator which has a closed chain. And Let $\textbf{q}_a$ actuated joint variables, and $\textbf{q}_u$ unactuated joint variables. And $\textbf{q}_o=[\textbf{q}_a^T\text{ }\textbf{q}_u^T]^T$. If there is a function relationship between $\textbf{q}_u$ and $\textbf{q}_u$ such that $\textbf{q}_u=\textbf{q}_u(\textbf{q}_a)$, there is a relationship below this text :
$$\dot{\textbf{q}}_o={\boldsymbol{\gamma}\dot{\mathbf{q}_a}}$$
$$\boldsymbol{\gamma} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{I}
 \\\frac{\partial \mathbf{q}_u}{\partial \mathbf{q}_a} \end{bmatrix}$$
I understand what it means. But I don't know why the relationship below this text makes sense :
$$\boldsymbol{\tau}_a = \boldsymbol{\gamma}^T \boldsymbol{\tau}_o $$
$\boldsymbol{\tau}_a$ is torques of actuated joints, and $\boldsymbol{\tau}_o$ is torques of unactuated joints. The book explains it is intuitive, but I want to know why it is true theorically.